# A function that can translate DNA sequence to binary code

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am designing a function that can translate DNA sequence to binary code in four dimension vector. e.g "A"-(1,0,0,0)| "G-(0,1,0,0)"...

We also find the () in for loop can actually influence the result. we hope to find the reason behind this.
e.g. 4-1:7-1 & (4-1):7-1 is totally different, we want to find the knowledge behind this

```
NC1 <- function(data){ 
  for(i in 1:length(data) ){
    if(i==1){ 
      DCfirst <- unlist(as.vector(strsplit(data[1],"",fixed = TRUE)))
      DCsecond <- matrix(0,nrow = length(data),ncol = length(DCfirst))
      DCsecond[1,] <-  DCfirst 
    }else{
      DCsecond[i,] <- unlist(as.vector(strsplit(data[i],"",fixed = TRUE)))
    }
  }
  return(DCsecond)
}

binary<- function(data){
  sequence_X<-NC1(data)
  N=ncol(sequence_X)
  X2<-matrix(NA,nrow=length(data),ncol=4*N)
  for (i in 1 : N){
    L1<-which(sequence_X[,i]=="A")
    L2<-which(sequence_X[,i]=="G")
    L3<-which(sequence_X[,i]=="C")
    L4<-which(sequence_X[,i]=="U")
    for (j in L1){
      X2[j, (4i-3):4i-1]<-unlist(c(1,0,0,0))
    }
    for (j in L2){
      X2[j, (4i-3):4i-1]<-unlist(c(1,0,0,0))
    }
    for (j in L3){
      X2[j, (4i-3):4i-1]<-unlist(c(1,0,0,0))
    }
    for (j in L4){
      X2[j, (4i-3):4i-1]<-unlist(c(1,0,0,0))
    }
  }
    return (X2)
}

TEST <- c("ACGUC","ACUAU","UCGUA","CGUCG","UAGUG")
binary(TEST)
```

The final result is showed us below:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
     [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0
[3,]     0     0     0
[4,]     0     0     0
[5,]     0     0     0
```

I hope my final sequence can all be translated to vector format. As can be seen from the results, all except the first element in each sequence cannot fully be translated to the vector format

this is the correct answer i hope to achieve:

[image]

this is the first time to use this to ask questions. I feel really sorry to be unable to convey the question clearly

Comment: 4-1:7-1 & (4-1):7-1 :- these are difference because of the order of operations, the colon ":" takes priority over the subtraction, essentially you are creating the following list: 4-1-1, 4-2-1, 4-3-1, ..., 4-7-1.  If you include the brackets you are doing 3-1, 4-1, ..., 7-1.

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: i have edited my questions, i feel really sorry for not conveying my problems clearly

Comment: Using the answer by @akrun, assign the lapply to `dat` and use the following should give you the described matrix: `do.call("rbind", lapply(dat, function(x) as.vector(t(x))))`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option in `base R` with `outer` and `==`.  We split the 'TEST' by `""`, do the elementwise comparison to give a `list` of logical `matric`es

```
f1 <- function(x, y) outer(x, y, FUN = `==`)
lapply(strsplit(TEST, ""), f1, c("A", "G", "C", "U"))
```

#### data

```
TEST <- c("ACGUC","ACUAU","UCGUA","CGUCG","UAGUG")
```

Comment: Much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would do this in a lapply-like operation.

#### Example:

```
TEST <- c("ACGUC","ACUAU","UCGUA","CGUCG","UAGUG")

vecDNA <- function(x){unlist(strsplit(x = x, split = "*"))}
binDNA <- function(x){
  data.frame(
    code=x, 
    G=as.numeric(x=="G"), 
    C=as.numeric(x=="C"), 
    A=as.numeric(x=="A"), 
    U=as.numeric(x=="U")
  )
}

T2 <- lapply(as.list(TEST),vecDNA)
T3 <- lapply(T2, binDNA)
T3
```

#### Result:

```
> T3
[[1]]
  code G C A U
1    A 0 0 1 0
2    C 0 1 0 0
3    G 1 0 0 0
4    U 0 0 0 1
5    C 0 1 0 0

[[2]]
  code G C A U
1    A 0 0 1 0
2    C 0 1 0 0
3    U 0 0 0 1
4    A 0 0 1 0
5    U 0 0 0 1

[[3]]
  code G C A U
1    U 0 0 0 1
2    C 0 1 0 0
3    G 1 0 0 0
4    U 0 0 0 1
5    A 0 0 1 0

[[4]]
  code G C A U
1    C 0 1 0 0
2    G 1 0 0 0
3    U 0 0 0 1
4    C 0 1 0 0
5    G 1 0 0 0

[[5]]
  code G C A U
1    U 0 0 0 1
2    A 0 0 1 0
3    G 1 0 0 0
4    U 0 0 0 1
5    G 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach, I created a multilevel list for each of your sequences coding the letters with `stringr::str_locate_all()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

TEST <- c("ACGUC","ACUAU","UCGUA","CGUCG","UAGUG")

coder <- function(string) {
  lapply(c("A","G","C","U"), function(x, y) {
    tmp <- rep(F, str_length(y))
    tmp[str_locate_all(y, x)[[1]][,1]] <- T
    tmp
  }, y = string) %>%
    setNames(c("A","G","C","U"))
}

dat <- lapply(TEST, coder) %>%
  setNames(TEST)
```

You can extract specific letters from a sequence with:

```
dat$ACGUC$G

[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

or a data frame with:

```
dat$ACGUC %>%
  bind_rows()

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  A     G     C     U    
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE
3 FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
5 FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE
```